Next.js "fetch failed" when using localhost as hostname
I made some middleware that automatically adds an "X-API-Key" request header to every request that matches with "/graphql", this in turn forwards the request to my external (hosted somewhere else) graphql endpoint.
Now what happens is that when accessing the endpoint from "localhost:3000/graphql" I get an ambiguous error saying "fetch failed", without any detailed explanation.
The weird thing is that, when using "127.0.0.1:3000/graphql" it does work. It's driving me crazy.
Why is it that the "fetch" fails? It's not a CORS issue since it's a server-side request, right?
Here's the code of my middleware:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function graphqlMiddleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // Check authentication here (if needed)

  if (
    !process.env.NEXT_SERVER_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT ||
    !process.env.NEXT_SERVER_GRAPHQL_KEY
  ) {
    throw new Error("Missing environment variables for GraphQL proxy");
  }

  // Only handle requests to /graphql
  if (!request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/graphql")) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  // Clone request headers and set additional headers
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  requestHeaders.set("X-API-Key", process.env.NEXT_SERVER_GRAPHQL_KEY || "");

  // Proxy the request to the GraphQL endpoint
  const response = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_SERVER_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, {
    method: request.method,
    headers: requestHeaders,
    body: request.body, // Forward the body of the original request
    redirect: "manual",
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  // Create a new response with the same body but different headers
  const responseHeaders = new Headers(response.headers);

  // Set additional headers on the response
  responseHeaders.set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
  responseHeaders.set("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
  responseHeaders.set("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'");
  responseHeaders.set("Referrer-Policy", "strict-origin-when-cross-origin");

  // Return a new NextResponse with the modified headers
  const newResponse = new NextResponse(await response.text(), {
    status: response.status,
    headers: responseHeaders,
  });

  return newResponse;
}


